# Embedding Razor views in class library as resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using VirtualPathProvider to provide themed views.

In action method I want to return a view by path

```
return View("~/Themes/SomeTheme.dll/Views/Content/Item.cshtml");
```

In Visual Studio Item.cshtml has a build action "Embedded Resource".
VirtualPathProvider finds that .cshtml file, but I get an error

```
The view at '~/Themes/SomeTheme.dll/Views/Content/Item.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.
```

I guess I have to compile that view and I've followed [these instructions](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/).

Now the VirtualPathProvider can't find the Item.cshtml because it's not an embedded resource anymore.

How do I solve this problem? I can't add reference to that SomeTheme.dll because activated theme is loaded dynamically at application start.

I've done this before with aspx files and those didn't need to be compiled. They worked out of the box as embedded resources.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, didn't catch this question. Did you manage to get the compiled views running now? If you're using the compiled version, you should not use the dll-name in the path.

Comment: I managed to get it work with a different approach. Made a blog post about it http://mikakolari.fi/blogi/aspnetmvc-3-plugin-architecture-with-embedded-razor-views/

Comment: Mika, the link to your blog doesn't seem to be valid anymore. Can you post the solution here? I'm running into the same issue with compiled Razor views.

Comment: I put it back online, but I must say there are some mysterious problems. I would take a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue with embedded aspx views. The compilation that happens when the page is viewed relies on some settings in the web.config of the views folder. The embedded resources aren't in the views folder, so don't use those settings and fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try `install-package EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider`

Answer (score 0):

Try [this solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/01/20/how-to-get-razor-intellisense-for-model-in-a-class-library-project.aspx) to handle intellisense in your View Class Library.  You may need to add the following line to that web.config.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Also, try adding @Inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage statements to each of your embedded views (or substitute the base clase you use) to handle this at runtime.