# "'ViewData' is not declared." when using MVC4 Razor Views in Class Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, class-library

Looking the various different suggestions and recommendations, like this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616511/embedding-razor-views-in-class-library-as-resources) I can't get working Razor Views in the Class Library. Non of the System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage properties are accessable, even if it's configured as a page Base Type. Here is my web.config in the Class Library:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Any ideas what else could be missing?

Comment: silly question....have u added mvc 4 dll in the project and are you upgrading your project from MVC 3 or something to MVC 4?

Comment: yes, I've added MVC4 using NuGet. Have references to System.Web.Helpers, Mvc, Razor, WebPages, WebPages.Razor.

Comment: Solved this problem eventually. Created new project as empty MVC 4 application and removed Web API references.